# MVC Partial view hides main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I am new to MVC. using MVC 3.

I have PersonMaster Controller as below... having following two Actions.

```
public ActionResult TopTenPersons()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        var persons = DatabaseHelper.Instance.Database.Query<Person_Master>("select top(10) from person_master").ToList();
        return View("_PersonGrid", persons);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var persons = DatabaseHelper.Instance.Database.Query<Person_Master>("select * from person_master").ToList();

        return View("_PersonGrid",persons);
        //return View();
    }
```

Then, index.cshtml view is as follows..

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyPracticeApp1.Models.Person_Master>
@section scripts{
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

<h2>Persons</h2>

<p>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Click to top 10 Persons","TopTenPersons", new AjaxOptions{
UpdateTargetId="tbl_person",
InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
HttpMethod="GET"
})
</p>
<div id="tbl_person">
@Html.Action("Index","PersonMaster");
</div>
```

..and partial view _PersonGrid.cshtml which is called above in index view is as follows...

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyPracticeApp1.Models.Person_Master>
@{
var persongrid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
@persongrid.GetHtml()
```

....But problem is that it directly shows partial view. It is not rendering Ajax Actionlink of index view. So, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Change `TopTenPersons` to return a `Partial View`, not a `View`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var persons = DatabaseHelper.Instance.Database.Query<Person_Master>("select * from person_master").ToList();

    return PartialView("_PersonGrid",persons);
}
```

Comment: it shows grid inside plain page... it does not show by top links application name and all...

Comment: Have you tried combining this with what Eray said and setting the Layout = null in the top of the Partial View?

Comment: yes.. see comment...and also Action link is not displaying which I want to show above grid.

Comment: What about if you change ActionLink to use RenderPartial instead? (Html.RenderPartial)

Comment: It shows perons grid but not the Ajax.ActionLink which is above that. What am I missing? Even the h2 tag is not displayed

Answer (score 1):

add layout=null to _PersonGrid.cshtml

seems like

```
@{
   Layout = null;
}
```

when you add this code It is not rendering full view..

Comment: this shows person grid in plain page.. with no default layout...and Action link is not displaying

Comment: ok i know but when you set layout = null it will rendering partial view. if you dont it will render like full page. i was experiencing an issue like yours. it works for me.

Comment: problem solved.. instead of returning partial view I returned Index view in index action.. and it solved